# How to retrieve the number of errors in a subform (FormType) in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a ProfileType Form in my UserBundle (extending from SonataUserBundle), in the ProfileType Form I added a sub form type (AddressType()).

**ProfileType**

```
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
    $builder
        ->add('gender')
        ->add('firstname')
        ->add('lastname')
        ->add('middlename')
        ->add('dateOfBirth', 'birthday', array('required' => false))
        ->add('phone')
        ->add('address', new AddressType(), array('required' => false));
    ;
   }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
   public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
   {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => $this->class,
           'validation_groups' => array('Profile', 'Address'),
           'cascade_validation' => true,
       ));
   }
```

**AddressType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('postalcode')
        ->add('houseNumber')
        ->add('houseNumberAddition')
        ->add('street')
        ->add('city')
        ->add('country')
    ;
}
```

In the **edit_profile_html.twig** I like to know if there are any errors specifically in the **AddressType**. But form.address.vars.errors does not return the number of invalid elements in AddressType. If I specifically check the errors for a element in AddressType it **does** return the correct count.

So: form.address.vars.errors.length is 0, but form.address.postalcode.var.errors.length work. But I do not want to check for all elements one by one.

```
        <fieldset {% if form.address.vars.errors|length>0 %} class="warning" {% endif %} >
            <legend>{% trans %}vg.userbundle.form.address.legend{% endtrans %}</legend>
            {{ form_rest(form.address) }}
        </fieldset>
```

**edit_profile_html.twig**

```
{% block subtitle %}{{ "title_user_account" | trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') }} - {{      "title_user_edit_profile" | trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  {% block fos_user_content %}
    <form novalidate action="{{ path('sonata_user_profile_edit') }}" method="POST">
        <fieldset {% if form.vars.errors|length>0 %} class="warning" {% endif %} >
            <legend>{% trans %}vg.userbundle.form.profile.legend{% endtrans %}</legend>
            {{ form_row(form.gender) }}
            {{ form_row(form.firstname) }}
            {{ form_row(form.lastname) }}
            {{ form_row(form.middlename) }}
            {{ form_row(form.dateOfBirth) }}
            {{ form_row(form.phone) }}
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset {% if form.address.vars.errors|length>0 %} class="warning" {% endif %} >
            <legend>{% trans %}vg.userbundle.form.address.legend{% endtrans %}</legend>
            {{ form_rest(form.address) }}
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="submit">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="submit" name="submit"
                           value="{{ 'sonata_user_submit'|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') }}"/></li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

  {% endblock %}
{% endblock content %}
```

So what is the correct way to retrieve the number of invalid elements of an 'embedded' FormType?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if a form and all of its elements are valid (=have no errors) using the "valid" variable (which I guess is what you want to do):

```
<fieldset {% if not form.address.vars.valid %} class="warning" {% endif %} >
```

Comment: thx! is this part also documentated somewhere in the official docs?

Comment: Seems not to be the case. Could you please open a ticket or PR on https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs?

Comment: may be helpful for some people: for anyone who wants to do this on the server side, use: 'error_bubbling' => TRUE,

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no way round to iterate through the object address and count the errors of child items.

```
{% for child in address %}
        {{ ...count errors... }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that every form item is an object which means that every child of "address" is an object as well.